# algorithm for 2D array that represents the topographic map of geographic surface

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, data-structures, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I'm having difficulty figuring out what to do with the following problem

The input will be 2D array A[n][n] numbers, representing the topographic map of the geographic surface. Also among the input will be a starting location (r,c). referring to entry A[r][c]

If you were planning hiking trails you would be bound by the differences in elevation between neighboring entries. A person could traverse between 2 adjacent locations, if their elevations differ by no more than 2). Adjacency follows just the 4 standard compass directions, (**so I assume no diagonals).** Therefore , a point on the map is considered reachable if it is traversable from A[r][c] through any sequence of adjacent entires.

Write an algorithm that computes all of the reachable locations. The output will be another 2D array R[n][n] with true/fals values. (I assume true means reachable, false means unreachable)

**If i understand this question correctly, I can create following matrix.
(suppose A[10][10] looks like this from A[0][0]:)**

50 51 54 58 60 60 60 63 68 71

48 52 51 59 60 60 63 63 69 70

44 48 52 55 58 61 64 64 66 69

44 46 53 52 57 60 60 61 65 68

42 45 50 54 59 61 63 63 66 70

38 42 46 56 56 63 64 61 64 62

36 40 44 50 58 60 66 65 62 61

36 39 42 49 56 62 67 66 65 60

30 36 40 47 50 64 64 63 62 60

50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50

**Both south and east are traversable from A[0][0] so reachable entries would be:**

**50** **51** 54 58 60 60 60 **63** 68 71

**48 52** **51** 59 60 60 **63 63** 69 70

44 48 **52** 55 58 61 **64 64 66** 69

44 46 **53** **52** 57 60 60 61 **65** 68

42 45 50 **54** 59 61 63 63 **66** 70

38 42 46 **56** **56** 63 64 61 **64 62**

36 40 44 50 **58** **60** 66 65 **62 61**

36 39 42 49 **56** **62** 67 66 65 **60**

30 36 40 47 50 **64** **64** **63 62 60**

50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50

so I can conclude that my resulting array should be

**1 1** 0 0 0 0 0 **1** 0 0

**1 1 1** 0 0 0 **1 1** 0 0

0 0 **1** 0 0 0 **1 1 1** 0

0 0 **1 1** 0 0 0 0 **1** 0

0 0 0 **1** 0 0 0 0 **1** 0

0 0 0 **1 1** 0 0 0 **1 1**

0 0 0 0 **1 1** 0 0 **1 1**

0 0 0 0 **1 1** 0 0 0 **1**

0 0 0 0 0 **1 1 1 1 1**

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I want to implement this in c code but i think its improper to ask for the code here. My plan is to implement this in pseudocode first then implementing in c code, which I will try doing it by myself =). I'm not sure as to where to start with my pseudocode. Can anyone please clarify this?

Thank you very much!

p.s just edited my matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [**Dijkstra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [**A-Star**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which are used in such a case. Further more you may have a look at **Graph Theory** basics in order to create an appropriate representation of your matrics.

Additionally you may need the [**Manhatten Distance**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) which can be used as a **heuristic** for the A-Star in your case.

There are many other algorihms  if you dive deeper into the topic of graph theory and search algorithms.

EDIT due to comment:

You can also use  [**Depth First Search (DFS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [**Breadth First Search (BFS)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). These algorithms are simpler to implement especially at the beginning.

At first you need to create an appropriate datastructur which represents the hightmap. These structur could look like this:

```
struct Vertex 
     int x                 // coordinate x
     int y                 // coordinate y
     Vertex neighbors[8]; // Array of all adjacent vertices 
     int height            // height
}
```

after that you can use the following pseudocode as an proposal taken from [Breadth first search and depth first search](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960215.html)
which already is aware of cycles within the graph, which would lead to infinite loops.

```
 dfs(vertex v) {
    visit(v); 
    for each neighbor w of v            
        if w is unvisited **and reachable** // reachable according to your hight differences
        {
        dfs(w); // recursive call to the dfs 
        add edge vw to tree T  //tree contains a result path in your
                               //case the second matrix
        }
    }
```

Some steps are missing within the pseudocode. For example the condition for 
abandon the DFS when visiting the goal.

Some additional notes:

- the DFS will find just a solution for your problem
- **Dijkstra** and **A-Star** will find the shortest (optimal) solution for the problem (shortest path from start to goal, taking into account the hight of your Vertices

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I searched for the algorithms you suggested, but it seems like it is an advanced topic for me (i'm just a begineer =D).

Comment: When your a able to create a "directed graph" from your matrics you could use Breadth First Search BFS or Depth First Search DFS. These algos are a little bit simpler to implement. But i have to say that especially Dijkstra is  widely used and therefore sample implementatiins available. Don't give up. The very beginning is always hard. But it is a quite interesting topic!

Comment: @oliver i hope it was just a mishap, because i know many people who try solve there problems by asking others. For me it was always better and gave me a better feeling to knew and understand the problem on my own. Anyway. Have a look at Graph Theory which neads mathmatics but leads to robotics, game-development, machine-learning and so on. Stay on course and i would really appriciate if i could help to solve you problem !